# mysql compare two tables

Tags: mysql, arrays, compare

I have a mysql database that has 2 table. the first table contains the user information, and the second table contains the votes. there is a common field between the two (userid).

but after checking the num rows in each table I found that the first table contains nearly 1000 users more than the second, so there are almost 1000 members whio didn't vote.

I want to query the two tables and get an array containing the userid of the members who didn't vote.

How to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join both tables and filter out which users don't have corresponding record in votes table.

```
SELECT id FROM members
LEFT JOIN votes ON userid=id
WHERE votes.userid IS NULL
```

Comment: sorry but this didn't work. there is no id, both of the two tables have a "userid". and when I changed "id" with "userid" in this query string, I got this message in phpmyadmin:

#1052 - Column 'userid' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: then just add table names before fields. LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.userid=members.userid